# How do install pyopencl using INDE instead of OpenCL SDK?

Tags: gpu, pyopencl

I'm a python newbie and I'm trying to install pyopencl. I've found Andreas Klöckner's website. And I'm trying to use the Windows 7 64bit, Python 2.7, Visual Studio 2010, Intel OpenCL SDK 1.5 directions to install. The problem is that Intel OpenCL SDK has been integrated into INDE. So I'm wondering what the equivalent library file is for C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\1.5\include and C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\1.5\lib\x64 ? After installing INDE, I didn't see anything under that specific file location.

Under C:\Intel\INDE, if I just look for folders that contain libraries I saw the code_builder_5.0.0.43 (contains OpenCL), IDEintegration (contains a bunch of stuff), the media_raw_accelerator_1.0.3, media_sdk_6.0.0.308. Anyone know which one I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

It's 'C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.0.0.43\include' and 'C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.0.0.43\lib\x64'

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a few points that could be useful to others who want to use PyOpenCL on Windows. First, if you are **not** a Python developer, you will want to use the Intel OpenCL Code Builder. When you install the INDE Suite, you integrate in Visual Studio and you get all the syntax highlighting amongst others. This video gives a great overview: http://bcove.me/xrcs5bze

The latest OpenCL 2.0 (as of time of writing) is now part of OpenCL Code Builder. In order to access the OpenCL framework to use with PyOpenCL, do the following installation on Windows (if not yet done):

Detailed instructions can be found here: http://wiki.tiker.net/PyOpenCL/Installation/Windows

1. Install Visual Studio
2. Install Python 2.7
3. Install NumPy
4. Install PyOpenCL
5. Install Intel INDE (OpenCL Code Builder component)

Once this is done, locate the `siteconf.py` file and edit accordingly. On my machine, I have INDE Update 2 which comes with OpenCL Code Builder 5.1.0.25 installed. 
Thus, the following lines are edited:

```
CL_INC_DIR = [r'C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\include']
CL_LIB_DIR = [r'C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\lib\x64', r'C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\lib\x86']
```

I hope that helped.